# Non-Jew and sick parents

Tags: gentiles, choleh-sick

I have a non-Jewish worker in my office who I have gotten to know very well over the years. Recently when I asked how he was doing he told me that his parents were very sick. When I told him that I would pray for them, he thanked me profusely.

We say that giving charity saves one from death. However, is there anything that **he** can do that will arouse/ merit רחמי שמים, so that his parents will have a speedy recovery?

Comment: Hi CT. This is purely speculative but all people regardless of background can pray directly to G-d. Your friend may  simply pray to G-d asking for a full recovery for his parents. Jews often recite tehilim (psalms) when seeking resolve to extrodinary situations. point is, Hashem listens to everyone's prayers. May your friend's parents have a refuse sh'lamah (a ful rovers.)

Comment: @JJLL That is born out in several explicit verses. God “hears the prayers of every mouth.”

Comment: Strangely some nusach says כל פה עמל ישראל ברחמים

Answer (score 2):

He should do acts of charity and kindness. Better yet, he should assist his parents to perform those acts. See [Daniel 4:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Daniel.4.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> 24: Indeed, O king, may my counsel please you, and with charity you will remove your sin and your iniquity by showing mercy to the poor; perhaps your tranquility will last."

Comment: Though Daniel was punished for giving this advice to Nevuchadnezer...it was because it was effective, not ineffective.

Answer (score 1):

He can visit elderly patients in hospital who do not have children to visit them.

Comment: How do you know 'that will arouse/ merit רחמי שמים, so that his parents will have a speedy recovery?'